# Make black sofa white in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I try to change a black sofa

[image]

into this color

[image]

But fails to do so even after looking on diffrent guides. I have played alot with levels, Hue and color replace tool with no success.

I Suspect that tha sofa is to black so I tried to first make it white but it generates alot of artifacts and it ends up looking like metal?

This was the best result I got and that is not vary good :

[image]

Edit:

This is the original image

[image]

Comment: The black area has too little info. Do you have a raw picytire of this. if so you will benefit from 16 bit processing

Comment: Have attached the original image, thats all I have :(

Comment: Thats not what raw means it means raw data from camera sensor.

Comment: Yes I know, but that camera do not give me RAW, only JPEG. So there is not to do here then?

Comment: well ist possible but a lot of work as the noise in the bottom of your sensor is going to become a problem. You could you knopw render a 3d object on top though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is on the comments but here is an actual answer.

A black object has too little information on the shadows. All information about what parts of the objects are dark because of them is merged with the blackness of the object itself.

The same happens to a white object. What is white because a reflection or what is because it is by the color.

Saturated colors like red or green are easier to change because they have the discting information. This is color, this is shadow, this is highlight.

So the ony thing you can do is play with the curves to add more shadows.

I added an extra layer, desaturated it, moved the levels to only have some shadowy zones and aplied a gausiann blur. Use multiply blending mode.

[image]

As you can see you only have stains of noise. Probably it would be better to paint shadows by hand in this case.

But the painfull truth is that not only you do not have detail because the blackness of the couch but because **the photo is totally flat because you use the built in flash**.

I understand you can not shoot in RAW, but next time try to.

1) Not use the built in flash.

2) Use a tripod and shoot an aditional image overexposed. Use this second image as a source for the couch information.